# Magento 1.6, Google Shopping / Products / Content

Tags: magento-1.6, google-shopping

Magento 1.6 was out at the beginning of this week but upgrading from 1.5.1 with the mage_googleshopping extension (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Magento+Core/extension/6887/mage_googleshopping) up to v.1.6 was not something feasible.

mage_googleshopping remained compatible only with 1.5. Any working alternative to have the mage_googleshopping extension available on a clean Magento 1.6 installation or we have to wait for a stable extension release which goes with v.1.6?

Cheers,
Bogdan

Comment: Same discussion here as well: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/241866/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have browsed the Internet and searched for a problem to this, eventually I've turned into this script which runes separately but it connects to the Magento DB. The scripts generates the file, which can be uploaded following a schedule to Google.

Besides the fact that the script is totally editable, you can fully monitor all the processes behind it. The Magento script still can't be removed from a 1.6 Magento version.

The script wasn't developed by me but I did update it according with the latest rules enforced from 22/9/2011 by Google.

```
<code>
<?php
define('SAVE_FEED_LOCATION','google_base_feed.txt');
set_time_limit(1800);
require_once '../app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');
try{
    $handle = fopen(SAVE_FEED_LOCATION, 'w');

    $heading = array('id','mpn','title','description','link','image_link','price','brand','product_type','condition', 'google_product_category', 'manufacturer', 'availability');
    $feed_line=implode("\t", $heading)."\r\n";
    fwrite($handle, $feed_line);

    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
    $products->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);
    $products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4);
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $prodIds=$products->getAllIds();

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

    $counter_test = 0;

    foreach($prodIds as $productId) {

        if (++$counter_test < 30000){

            $product->load($productId);

            $product_data = array();
            $product_data['sku'] = $product->getSku();
            $product_data['mpn'] = $product->getSku();

            $title_temp = $product->getName();
            if (strlen($title_temp) > 70){
                $title_temp = str_replace("Supply", "", $title_temp);
                $title_temp = str_replace("  ", " ", $title_temp);
            }
            $product_data['title'] = $title_temp;


            $product_data['description'] = substr(iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",$product->getDescription()), 0, 900);
            $product_data['Deeplink'] = "http://www.directmall.co.uk/".$product->getUrlPath(); 
            $product_data['image_link'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA).'catalog/product'.$product->getImage();

            $price_temp = round($product->getPrice(),2);
            $product_data['price'] = round($product->getPrice(),2) + 5;

            $product_data['brand'] = $product->getData('brand');

            $product_data['product_type'] = 'Laptop Chargers &amp; Adapters';
            $product_data['condition'] = "new";
            $product_data['category'] = $product_data['brand'];
            $product_data['manufacturer'] = $product_data['brand'];

            $product_data['availability'] = "in stock";

            foreach($product_data as $k=>$val){
                $bad=array('"',"\r\n","\n","\r","\t");
                $good=array(""," "," "," ","");
                $product_data[$k] = '"'.str_replace($bad,$good,$val).'"';
            }

            echo $counter_test  . " ";

            $feed_line = implode("\t", $product_data)."\r\n";
            fwrite($handle, $feed_line);
            fflush($handle);

        }

    }

    fclose($handle);
}
catch(Exception $e){
    die($e->getMessage());
}</code>
```

1. Change www.directmall.co.uk into what you need.
2. Assign the proper permissions.
3. Fully updated according with Google's requirements.

Comment: Hi Bogdan, may I ask what the code on the price line does? I don't understand what the 2 and + 5 do.  $product_data['price'] = round($product->getPrice(),2) + 5;

Comment: Great question - it seems i forgot to comment that out - well I'm publishing the prices with 2 decimals (so it's £9.44 or £3.32 and not £3.445 nor £9.3) and I'm adding 5£ above the result :-) If you want just to publish the price - do it in the simple way: product_data['price'] = round($product->getPrice(),2); you need the round function - it proves results with Google.

Comment: So if I wanted to add 20% VAT to the price before sending it to Google I could * 1.2, then round the number to 2? Do you have any links showing that rounding improves results with Google?

Comment: It's for marketing purposes, the rounding can be removed without problems.

Comment: Can I ask about the product visibility? How can I limit the products to exclude those set to 'not visible individually'?

Comment: There should be a field called "visibility". Search within the current database and see what value a visible product has on the field "visibility". Then, change the query above so that you'll select all the items which have only that value on the "visibility" field.

Comment: This is still working in Magento 1.9.2.2.   Make sure you also change product_type and product_category to match whatever applies to your products. For a reference of Google Shopping's categories refer to [link]http://www.gootax.com/