# Magento 1.7, Google Shopping / Products / Content

Tags: api, magento

I have this problem:

I'm using this Google Content API for Shopping  1.7.0.0 (http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Magento+Core/extension/6887/mage_googleshopping) on Magento 1.7.0.2 but when I submit products it stuck after first one.

All options and attributes are set and its all fine. I even get first of products in Google Merchant Products list but script stops after first one and I get this massage:

**Google Shopping synchronization process is running** with a rotating loading icon on the submit button and that could run all day long.

I can reset this process with:

```
update core_flag set state='0' where flag_code='googleshopping';
```

PHP memory limit, execution time and max post are highest possible values, I don't think that's the problem because this happen even if I try to submit 1 or 2 items.

Comment: Your sql about resetting the process flag was helpful for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since last week, I've been seeing the same problem on Magento Enterprise 1.12.0.2 with the same Google Content API for Shopping installed. It's been working fine for product sets in three stores for many months. Now, I was able to complete a synchronize to delete some expired products, but any attempt to add products produces the same Google Shopping synchronization process is running with a rotating loading icon that you're seeing. We've had similar non-productive results from increasing memory limits etc.
The problem seems to occur whether 1 or many items get submitted. I've been using the same process reset you have.
I was able to add one product last week that had Type set. Although the Summary of Product Attributes http://support.google.com/merchants/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1344057#US
shows Product type as optional for non-apparel products, could they have changed this to required without telling us all?

Comment: Don't think so, it's still 'highly recommended' only. I think it's a magento problem. I give up from this module and now I build the same feed with a custom script (based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210620/magento-1-6-google-shopping-products-content) and all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Good news - per thread http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/303448/#t421584

made the change to GoogleShopping/Model/Service/Item.php from line 64: which was:

```
$published = $this->convertContentDateToTimestamp($entry->getPublished()->getText());
```

and per the thread is now:

$published = date();

and our products now add into GoogleShopping again, en masse.